# iOS & iCloud: ubiquityIdentityToken and password change or device restores

Tags: ios, icloud

My client recently got emails from customers reporting the following problems with an app that checks for the iCloud ubiquity token on each app launch (`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];`):

- when a device was restored from backup, sometimes the app detects a mismatch of the current and the previous token. Does the `ubiquityIdentityToken` change when restoring from backup?
- in one case the user got a new device, changed the iCloud password and restored the device from backup. The app detects a mismatch of the token. Does the `ubiquityIdentityToken` change when the iCloud password is changed?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing that the `ubiquityIdentityToken` definitely changes when you restore a backup to a new device - such as when copying an old device backup across to a new device.

This behaviour does not seem to be documented - I'm guessing the fact it is reported in the documentation as returning an *'opaque token'* means this is calculated on the combination of some kind of device UUID and an iCloud account UUID - hence the token changes when the device changes. Either that, or the device UUID is not preserved when a device is wiped and restored, and a new one is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

I've been starting to look into this area and can't find much information, as it is described by Apple as an "opaque token", so I'll put down what I have observed in case it helps anyone,

The token is a series of 40 8-digit hexadecimal number groups. Most of those number groups don't change.

Asking for a token from a different app, on a different device, OR with a different iCloud account gives values that differ entirely for the 17th to 22nd number groups.

The rest of the numbers remain the same, even across unrelated users' devices.

I only found one exception- from a client's device where they are having a sync problem. In that case more than half of the numbers were different. I am investigating why this would be at the moment.